Added frame is not working between two collection view on navigate back page & when its initialize component app gets crashed MAUI .NET
So OnAppearing(), I am calling InitializeComponent() as you can see in a below details.
public Settings(Item selectedItem)
{
    
}

protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    Items1 = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    await Task.Delay(500);
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeItemsH();
    InitializeItems();
    BindingContext = this;
} 

when I get back to this page by navigating from another page. the app is getting crashed on IOS and windows (start without debugging). [on windows debugging its totally working fine]
as I have used InitializeComponent() here for clear the stack so function will be clickable.
you can check below XAML.


<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame BorderColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="10" Padding="5" Margin="10">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>
<Frame x:Name="FaceAuthSwitchFrame" 
    Margin="10,20,10,0"
       BorderColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}">
    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="20"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="face_id_logo.png"
               HeightRequest="25" 
               Background="White"/>
        <StackLayout WidthRequest="50">
            <Switch x:Name="fcidswitch"
                    IsVisible="True"
                    OnColor="Green"
                    ThumbColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Activate Face Id Detection"
               HeightRequest="20"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</Frame>
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged1"
                HeightRequest="85"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                Background="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame BorderColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                   CornerRadius="0"
                   Padding="1"
                   Margin="10">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                             VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                           Background="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                           HeightRequest="40"
                           WidthRequest="40"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           TextColor="White"
                           FontSize="10"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Span="1" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>



I have try run the page without frame its totally working fine, but whenever I uncomment the frame component app gets crashed. don't get understand why its working on IOS and Windows[start without debugging]

Did you try to use the Border instead of the Frame? The official document said: "The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement."

Thanks for the suggestion, I have already tried with border, it's not working.

Why are you calling InitializeComponent(); in OnAppearing?

InitializeComponent belongs in the constructor.  If you put it in OnAppearing it may get called more than once

What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by attempting to call InitializeComponent()? Please see my answer below explaining why this shouldn't be done. Since it's not clear what you're trying to do, I only answered why this isn't working, but not how you can solve your original problem.

InitializeComponent() should only be called once per page or view and only in the constructor. It's practically the constructor call for the XAML part of your page or view.
The InitializeComponent() method is auto-generated for each class that has a XAML part and makes a call to LoadFromXaml(), which then constructs the UI from the compiled XAML code and wires up the C# and XAML parts at runtime, sets up bindings and event handlers, etc.1
This should only happen once, otherwise, if you call InitializeComponent() in the OnAppearing() method, you will re-instantiate the XAML, which will lead to all sorts of unwanted side-effects - and apparently also crashes. Note that calling LoadFromXaml() is a very expensive operation and should not be called directly unless it cannot be avoided for some reason.
Important: OnAppearing() gets called more than once. In fact, it gets called every time a page comes (back) into view, which also means that it is called when you navigate from one page to another already existing page. Your code therefore calls LoadFromXaml() multiple times (indirectly) which leads to the effects you're seeing.

1: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/runtime-load

Thanks for the clarification, Now I am using InitializeComponent() into the constructor.
I am using InitializeComponent() into onappering() because whenever I navigate back to the settings [page] from the next page. the other options are not clickable that's why I initialize component on onappering(). its just working for me like stack clear of the page. whatsoever will find another solution for stack clear rather than writing into the onappering().

I have try run the page without frame its totally working fine, but whenever I uncomment the frame component app gets crashed. Have you tired this way: put the Frame and the control/layout inside it into the ContentView, then use ContentView(custom control) instead of using Frame directly.
